# Trying to block access to file

Tags: asp.net, file, download, block, iis-8

Ok, I have an asp.net application and inside this application, I have a folder with excel files.  These excel files contain protected information, and should not be publicly viewable.  I'm trying to make it so that someone could not type in the hyperlink of one of the files and view the data.I have a web.config file inside the directory that I am concerned about.  It reads

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

but it doesn't work, and the files are still accessable.  How would I accomplish this?

I'm also not using ASP.NET Membership roles in my application, and I just want to allow access to the files once someone is authenticated.  How would I allow them access?

I'm hosting this on IIS 8.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like I should have just researched a little longer.  Adding:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

To my application's main Web.Config seems to have done it.